# Configure my php.ini for running Facebook php sdk

Tags: php, facebook

I am having problems with using the Facebooks php sdk. When printing the

> > $facebook->getSignedRequest()
> >     the print doesn't show any 'page' or 'user' values.

I also tryed to print the $_REQUEST['signed_request'] and all I get is

> > Notice: Undefined index: signed_request

Could it be some settings in my php.ini file that I've missed to do?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue? If yes? Could you please share your solution?

Answer (score 0):

This is only going to possibly solve half the issue, but remember $_REQUEST['signed_request'] not $_REQUEST('signed_request');

**EDIT:** Ignore the last part as you mentioned, here is your answer:

You are getting variables just not the ones you want. It is returning a signed request, and you need to decrypt the request using your private key. Heres how:

```
function parse_signed_request($signed_request, $secret) {
  list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2); 

  // decode the data
  $sig = base64_url_decode($encoded_sig);
  $data = json_decode(base64_url_decode($payload), true);

  if (strtoupper($data['algorithm']) !== 'HMAC-SHA256') {
    error_log('Unknown algorithm. Expected HMAC-SHA256');
    return null;
  }

  // check sig
  $expected_sig = hash_hmac('sha256', $payload, $secret, $raw = true);
  if ($sig !== $expected_sig) {
    error_log('Bad Signed JSON signature!');
    return null;
  }

  return $data;
}

function base64_url_decode($input) {
  return base64_decode(strtr($input, '-_', '+/'));
}
```

Pass the signed request and your app secret into that and it will return your array. Im sure there is a way to do it with the Facebook SDK but im not not sure as I don't use it.

More Info: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/

Goodluck!

Comment: Of course, it was a typo misstake when writing the post here. I use $_REQUEST['signed_request'].

Comment: Could you provide more of your code then please? So we can identify the problem. I cant think of an issue with php.ini that would cause this.

Comment: require ('php-sdk/facebook.php');

// Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'myAppId',
  'secret' => 'mySecret', 
  'cookie' => true,
   
));

  $signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();

When printing $signed request all I get is following:
Array ( [algorithm] => HMAC-SHA256 
[code] => 2.AQBw-BIdk15ur3XD.3600.1330430400.5-634829875|X8Oq1fMWhdW2hZunCRSIYIqf8Ms 
[issued_at] => 1330423787 
[user_id] => myUserId )

Comment: I have tried the the code that you have provided, but the problem lies in the $_REQUEST['signed_request'] and that is doesn't have any values stored.I have tried the same code on another host and it works just fine, that is why I thought it was some setting in the php.ini file that was not right, or maybe it some other settings that I missed?

Comment: Sanela, why are you trying to get $_REQUEST['signed_request']? Its not parsed that way. Facebook does not parse the request parameter, it is parsing the returned data through JSON which PHP is decoding.. You simply use your $signed_request and run it through that function.

Comment: If i understand you right, I get the $signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();

And then use the function that you provided: 
parse_signed_request($signed_request, mySecret);

Using this, I get the error message: 
Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in.

Comment: Not 100% sure, but try parse_signed_request($signed_request['code'], 'mySecret'); If that doesn't work, I will help you on chat.

Comment: Are you sure you added your secret?

Comment: Yes, i am sure. I am using $facebook->getApiSecret() to get the right secret.

Comment: Please email me michael@mjth.org and I may be able to assist you further.